# java compareTo substracts values

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I am using a `Binarytree` and for my

```
removeNode(E value) method (E extends Comparable<E>),
```

I use the method `value.compareTo(root.getData())`. Unfortunately it doesn't compare, but substracts both values and returns the result as an integer.
Does anybody know, why?
The Nodes and the tree are build with short like

```
Node<Short> n=new Node<Short>((short) 20);
```

EDIT:

```
    BinNodeGen<Short> rootNode = new BinNodeGen<Short>((short)20);
    BinNodeGen<Short> NodeA2 = new BinNodeGen<Short>((short)10);
    BinNodeGen<Integer> NodeA3 = new BinNodeGen<Short>((short)35);
    BinTreeGen<Short> voll3 = new BinTreeGen<Short>();
    voll3.setRootNode(rootNode);
    rootNode.setLeftChild(NodeA2);
    rootNode.setRightChild(NodeA3);
    voll3.insertNode((short)2);
    voll3.insertNode((short)1);
    voll3.insertNode((short)3);
    voll3.insertNode((short)14);
    voll3.insertNode((short)18);
    voll3.insertNode((short)17);
    voll3.insertNode((short)24);
    voll3.insertNode((short)28);
    voll3.insertNode((short)25);
    voll3.insertNode((short)30);
    voll3.removeNode(35);
    ...
```

and the method:

```
    public void removeNode(E value) {
    if (value.compareTo(root.getData()) == 0) {
```

However, when I try

```
System.out.println(value.compareTo(root.getData());
```

I get the value of value minus root.getData()!

Comment: We cannot debug invisible code. Post the relevant portions here.

Comment: ehm ... what? compareTo always returns an int. what's the problem with that?

Comment: What do you imagine that `compareTo` should return?

Comment: edited.
I imagine that it would return 1,0 or -1. But I however get the difference.

Comment: that's a possible way to implement it, but it actually returns a positive number (not zero), a negative number, or zero

Comment: See my answer. It will actually print the difference. Positive if the number is greater, negative if it is smaller than the given number.

Answer (score 4):

That's exactly what `compareTo` is supposed to return :

> Returns: a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this
>   object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

See [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is what Short does according to the documentation :

the value 0 if this Short is equal to the argument Short; a value less than 0 if this Short is numerically less than the argument Short; and a value greater than 0 if this Short is numerically greater than the argument Short (signed comparison).

So this should return 0 if you are comparing equal shorts :

```
Short s = new Short("12");
    Short anotherShort = new Short("12");
    if(s.compareTo(anotherShort) == 0){
        System.out.println("Equal");

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not Equal");
    }
```

This should print "Not Equal".

A more defined example will be this according to : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/short_compareto.htm

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.lang.*;

public class ShortDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

// create short object and assign value to it
short val1 = 50, val2 = 200, val3 = 50;
Short Shortval1 = new Short(val1);
Short Shortval2 = new Short(val2);
Short Shortval3 = new Short(val3);

// returns less than 0 if this Short is less than the argument Short
int cmp = Shortval1.compareTo(Shortval2); 
System.out.println("" + Shortval1 + " is less than " + Shortval2 + ", difference = " + cmp);

// returns 0 if this Short is equal to the argument Short
cmp = Shortval1.compareTo(Shortval3); 
System.out.println("" + Shortval1 + " is equal to " + Shortval3 + ",difference = " + cmp);

// returns greater than if this Short is greater than the argument Short
  cmp = Shortval2.compareTo(Shortval1); 
  System.out.println("" + Shortval2 + " is more than " + Shortval1 + ",
 difference = " + cmp);
 }
}
```

And this prints :

```
 50 is less than 200, difference = -150
 50 is equal to 50, difference = 0
 200 is more than 50, difference = 150
```